# Get list containing lists with max values

Tags: python, list

I have a list with coordinates and other parameter. I have to make a new list or edit the initial one with duplicate coordinates that have the largest parameter.
For example:

```
list = [

[(34.5464,58.3435),35]
[(34.5464,58.3435),17]
[(34.5464,58.3435),23]
[(36.6575,62.6545),89]
[(31.2101,45.9789),2]
[(31.2101,45.9789),12]
[(37.5462,48.7521),78]

]
```

I need to have this one:

```
list_dub_max = [

[(34.5464,58.3435),35]
[(31.2101,45.9789),12]

]
```

Comment: Don't you need `(37.5462,48.7521),78`? Anyway, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
def getFilteredList(l):
    list_dub_max = {}
    for val in l:
        if (val[0] in list_dub_max and list_dub_max[val[0]] < val[1]) or val[0] not in list_dub_max:
             list_dub_max[val[0]] = val[1]
    return [[k,v] for k,v in list_dub_max.iteritems()]
```

where `l` is your `list`:

```
l = [
[(34.5464,58.3435),35],
[(34.5464,58.3435),17],
[(34.5464,58.3435),23],
[(36.6575,62.6545),89],
[(31.2101,45.9789),2],
[(31.2101,45.9789),12],
[(37.5462,48.7521),78],
]
```

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: your list `l` should have commas separating the elements

Answer (score 2):

Use `dict` like:

```
>>> data = [[(34.5464, 58.3435), 35], [(34.5464, 58.3435), 17], [(34.5464, 58.3435), 23], [(36.6575, 62.6545), 89], [(31.2101, 45.9789), 2], [(31.2101, 45.9789), 12], [(37.5462, 48.7521), 78]]
>>> result={}
>>> for t,v in data:
    x = result.get(t)
    if x:
        if x<v: result[t]=v
    else:
        result[t] = v


>>> result = result.items()
>>> result
[((37.5462, 48.7521), 78), ((31.2101, 45.9789), 12), ((36.6575, 62.6545), 89), ((34.5464, 58.3435), 35)]
```

If you are required to have `list` of `list` instead of `list` of `tuple` (like above), you can do this (like other answer):

```
result = [[k,v] for k,v in result.iteritems()]
```

Comment: I tried your method, actually it didn't work. Error is after a line `for t,v in data: too many values to unpack`. According to your comment to my question I need only values that are duplicate in the initial list but only those which have the greatest value among duplicates.

Comment: The above code excerpt is taken directly from IDLE after running the code. So the error is somewhere else; probably in your `data`...